# Not able to get the values from soap response

Tags: java, soap, ksoap2

This is my code

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("MobileNbr","9959077764");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
        System.out.println(response);
        String result = response.getProperty(0);
        System.out.println(result);
    }catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the Response I'm getting.

```
GetCabListResponse{GetCabListResult=<CabList><status>0</status><cab>AP09BS9127</cab><cab>AP09BS9126</cab></CabList>; }
```

This is the result getting from response.getProperty(0);

```
<CabList><status>0</status><cab>AP09BS9127</cab><cab>AP09BS9126</cab></CabList>
```

I want the values of status and cab

Comment: Seems like inside your JSON response there's another XML response object. For extracting you can go different ways - from JAXB to simple regex patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex solution to extract your data from returned XML:

```
    String cab ="<CabList><status>0</status><cab>AP09BS9127</cab><cab>AP09BS9126</cab></CabList>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<status>([^<]+)</status><cab>([^<]+)</cab>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(cab);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Status: " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Cab: " + m.group(2));
    }
```

Multiple cabs:

```
    String cab ="<CabList><status>0</status><cab>AP09BS9127</cab><cab>AP09BS9126</cab></CabList>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<status>([^<]+)</status>((<cab>([^<]+)</cab>)*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(cab);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Status: " + m.group(1));
        List<String> cablist = Arrays.asList(m.group(2).replace("<cab>", "").replace("</cab>", "#").split("#"));
        System.out.println("Cab: " + cablist);          
    }
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks to it. But I have 2 cab no. there. I'm only getting the first value. How to get the second value?

Comment: a okay- you'll need to modify a bit

Comment: Yup. Thanks. I did that. Thankyou very much for helping me. I have a doubt. How can I get the size of the xml result?

Comment: The size? In bytes? Or in how far?

Comment: how far. the result is dynamic. There may be two or more values. So If I need to know how many cabs are there, then how can I get that no.?

Comment: check my second code for multiple cabs: You could simply do `cablist.size()` then.

Comment: Thankyou so much jan. It is so helpful